# Unity 4.6 Throwing JAVA_HOME reference error when I imported Google Analytics Package

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I couldn't find any proper answer that solves my issue.

First, here's what I'm using:

- List item
- Unity 4.6
- Android SDK Tools 26

Now, the problem is that once I imported Google Analytics V4 Package into my unity Android project, I started getting this error:

[image]

I know it's telling me that Unity is unable to find the JDK path in the environment variables, but the problem is that it's already there.

Here's my environment variables:

[image]

I'm 100% sure of the paths.
I tried every possible combination, installed 32-bit JDK, installed and updated Android SDK tools, Google play services and NDK.

I even restarted my laptop several times so System Environment Variables can take effect, but I'm still facing the same issue.

My Android SDK location in Unity is 100% correct, as it was working before.

I spent a lot of time googling this, but no answer worked for me.

Does anyone have an idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone came by this in the future, Google Analytics for Unity V4 is NOT compatible with Unity 4.6

It's so strange since i didn't find any clue about it on the web.